# How to make a video hyperlink so that when a viewer clicks on it the video will begin at a certain second?

Tags: support

Let's say I came across a phrase in a video that I don't understand. So make a hyperlink to the video, but I want the video to begin when clicked on at that very second the phrase is said. How do I do that. Until recently I did't know that it was possible, but one of my questions has been edited recently, so I wander now how I can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a function of YouTube, not SE. Play your video to where you want it to start then pause it. Click the "Share" button, check the "Start at" box, then click "copy" to copy the URL:

[image: Screenshot of a YouTube Share dialog]

Then, just insert that link into your post:
[Magnet "Midi" Music System (I Want Your Feedback) - Marble Machine X #25](https://youtu.be/iFuUSe44jtk?t=5m32s) starting at 5:32.

Comment: As a footnote, I've noticed that this may not work in all browsers. Sometimes the video starts at the beginning, even with the modified link. So it still might be a good idea to include the information in your answer itself, like you've done here.